# Commiting to FragmentManager after onSelectItem

Tags: android, android-fragments

My acitivity has a `Menu` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). I am going to make something like:

1. When somebody select from menu `Option X` I would like show a `FragmentDialog F` .
2. If user clicks on `OK` on `F` then I would like to display another `FragmentDialog G`/

A. Is the first step safe? I mean: When I display a Fragment I have to commit to the `FragmentManager`. As you know we can commit to the `FragmenManager` if and only if the `Activity` is not stopped.
Can I be sure that it is safe? Why?

B. The same question, but for the second step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity and Fragment life-cycles are closely tied together. See the official documentation for [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) to know more on this.

Now the question about committing to `FragmentManager`. You should commit to `FragementManager` when your activity is active and restored(if destroyed for some reasons). And since life-cycles of fragment and activity are closely tied, you can be rest assured that if your fragment is active, your activity would also be active(answer to question B).

So **Yes**, It is completely safe.

Comment: Thanks! I can be assured that my Fragment ( and therefore activity) is active because it is foreground?

Comment: If you are committing the fragment transaction in the right lifecycle methods then you are safe. For example you can't commit any transactions after activity's `onSaveInstanceState` is called.

Comment: You said something like: the sky is blue if there is no cloud. Obvious.